# Distance between real finite dimensional linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Is there a usual distance between linear subspaces ($V,W$) of an n-dimensional normed vector space with inner product?

In the case of hyper-planes one could use the angle (based on the inner product of the vector space). What can be used in the case of subspaces with lower dimension (not necessarily equal)? e.g. $dim(V)= n-2$ and $dim(W) = n-4$

Thanks

Comment: Well, the word "distance" is already taken. If you call something "distance", you want it to be a distance, i.e. a metric. Your question is rather vague, since you do not add any reasonable condition that your "distance" should satisfy.

Comment: I need the usual properties of a distance (maybe measure?) d(x,x)=0 iff x=x, d(x,y)>= 0 , etc...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is, if both subspaces have the same dimension. You can actually make the set of $k$-dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V$ into a metric space (a manifold, in fact) called the [Grassmannian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian), denoted $\mathrm{Gr}(k,V)$. The distance between two subspaces $W$ and $W'$ is then $\|P_W-P_{W'}\|$ where $P_X$ denotes projection onto $X$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm.

Comment: Thanks Alex Becker! What happens when the subspaces are of different dimension?

Comment: @JuanPi Then there is no notion I know of. If the dimension of $V$ is $n$ and the dimensions of $W,W'$ are $k,n-k$ we can use the duality of $k$ and $n-k$ dimensional subspaces to consider both as $k$ dimensional subspaces, but otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: Why not use the same definition regardless of dimension?

Comment: @JonasMeyer How would that let you compare two subspaces of different dimension? The Grassmannian is dimension-specific.

Comment: @AlexBecker: There is no problem finding distances between orthogonal projections with ranges of arbitrary dimension.  The set of subspaces with this distance might be of interest, depending on what JuanPi wants to use it for.  It amounts to the same as using your definition on each Grassmannian, and defining the distance between spaces of different dimensions to be $1$.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Ah, I see what you mean.